# AngularJs how to create a list of same services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Service who can add by a user. It can be one or more.

I have a button to add a Service

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addService()">
    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
    </span>Add Service
</button>
```

When i click Add Service angular should creare a new Service in a list of services.

I have two textareas for Informations of the Service.

```
<label for="usr">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"></br>
<label for="usr">Service:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="service"></br>
```

When i click on the Add Service Button a knew Service Button should be generated with this textareas.

How can generate that and add the new Service to a list of services?

Comment: Paste some controller code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.services = [];
$scope.addService = function() {
    var newService = {
        name : 'a name',
        service : 'a service'
    };
    $scope.services.push(newService);
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="service in services"><label for="usr">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{service.name}"></br>
<label for="usr">Service:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{service.service}"></br></div>
```

Comment: how would you keep a track of which service is created for which input elements?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `ng-model` which will take care of 2 way binding fields to scope object

```
<label for="usr">Name:</label>
<input ng-model="newService.name"></br>
<label for="usr">Service:</label>
<input ng-model="newService.service"></br>
```

Then in controller

```
$scope.addService = function() {
     // copy and push newService object to array
    $scope.services.push(angular.copy($scope.newService));
    // reset newService object to clear fields
    $scope.newService = {};   

}
```

If you use a form for this you can use angular validation and move the `ng-click` to `ng-submit` on the form. `ng-submit` won't trigger if validation fails